# Passing Data to Independent Component React

Tags: react-router, reactjs

I have this `HomeContainer` component, `Home` component and this `Header` component.

1. `HomeContainer` contains the `state of city` and `<Home city={this.props.city} />`
2. `Home` contains stateless function and contains JSX. so via `this.props` i can access `HomeContainer's city`

Problem - I want to send the data to `Header` so that i can update the city in header whenever someone inputs something in the input field

I think The `Main` component has access to child components but the `Main` component is called via routes so i am not able to figure this out.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a jsx structure similar to:

```
<Main>
  <Header />
  <HomeContainer />
</Main>
```

Since the `city` property is to be used by both `<Header />` and `<HomeContainer />`, then it shouldn't be defined in `<HomeContainer />`

`city` should instead be defined as a state in `<Main />` and passed down to both `<Header />` and `<HomeContainer />`

This implies that you also define the callback to `changeCity()` in `<Main />` and pass it down to `<HomeContainer />` as a prop.

This way, both `<Header />` and `</HomeContainer>` will be updated with changes to the `city` attribute

Comment: Ohh that was so simple. I was not thinking that way. It was the first concept of react.
Thanks a lot @Cent.

Comment: Haha yeah. Easy gets lost within complex logic a lot @Siddharth . You can select as answer if it's the answer you seek